# For which $z \in \mathbb c$ does this series converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

$f(z)=\sum_1^\infty  \frac{(2z)^{2k}}{2k(2k-1)}$

I didn't know how to start so I just tried the ratio test.

If $|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|>0$ then the series converges.

$\implies$ $\frac{\frac{(2z)^{2k+2}}{(2k+2)(2k+1)}}{\frac{(2z)^{2k}}{2k(2k-1)}}>0$$\iff$ $\frac{(2z)^{2k+2}}{(2k+2)(2k+1)}\cdot\frac{2k(2k-1)}{(2z)^{2k}}\iff \frac{(2z)^2\cdot2k(2k-1)}{(2k+2)(2k+1)}$

I am stuck here. Is this even the right method to use or are there much easier ways of checking for which $z \in \mathbb c$ the series converges?

Comment: You have got the condition for ratio test wrong.

Comment: The series is convergent for every $z$ such that $|z|\leq\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Your method is OK! Just carry on.  You should have $4|z|^2<1$.

Comment: @voldemort Can you tell me what the correct condition is?

Comment: @Rzeta: Let me google that for you.. ah here it is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#The_test

Comment: @voldemort woops. Yeah I am retarded. I was actually looking at that and missed it. Thanks

Comment: @Rzeta: No you are not retarded.. It's sometimes easy to miss a condition or two..

Comment: @voldemort I get really frustrated when I make silly mistakes like that. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the module of the ratio and pass to the limit you find

$$(2|z|)^2\frac{2k(2k-1)}{(2k+2)(2k+1)}\xrightarrow{k\to\infty}4|z|^2<1\iff |z|<\frac12$$
so the radius of convergence is $R=\frac12$. We verify easily that the domain of convergence is $\overline D(0,\frac12)$: the closed disc of radius $\frac12$.

Comment: Thanks. Is the radius of convergence something that only makes sense in $\mathbb C$ ?

Comment: No it makes sense in $\Bbb R$ too!